# Generate list of numbers fron N to 1 in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am trying to generate a list of numbers from N to 1 without using any build-in predicated such as findall or numlist. What am I doing wrong ?

```
    pred(N,[H|T]):-  H is N, N1 is N-1, pred(N1,T).
    pred(1,[]).
```

I keep getting ERROR: Out of global stack

Comment: You don't need `H is N` (`is/2` is for arithmetic expression evaluation - see the documentation). You can put `pred(N, [N|T]) :- N1 is N-1, pred(N1, T).` But something is missing... Is there any  condition you assume here about `N`? Can it be any value at all for this clause? You need a condition to avoid the infinite recursion...

Comment: Also your base case is wrong. Is the list of number from 1 down to 1 really the empty list, `[]`?

Comment: I switched the order of the clauses and removed H is N , also switched 1 with 0 in pred(1,[]).  Thank you !

Comment: Just switching clauses isn't enough. That gets you a solution, but then yields a stack overflow if you ask for more solutions (`;`). You need a condition.

Comment: Can you please put up the updated version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order of your clauses. Put the second clause first, otherwise it has no chance to contribute (i.e. to halt) and the first clause continues to count down to negative infinity.

Of course even better is to make the two clauses mutually exclusive by adding a simple test as the first goal to your first clause.

Answer (score 3):

The most complete solution would be:

```
pred(1, [1]).
pred(N, [N|T]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N-1,
    pred(N1, T).
```

Without the `N > 1` condition you can still get a stack overflow:

```
| ?- pred(3, L).

L = [3,2,1] ? ;

Fatal Error: global stack overflow (size: 32768 Kb, reached: 32765 Kb, environment variable used: GLOBALSZ)
```

But with the `N > 1` condition:

```
| ?- pred(3, L).

L = [3,2,1] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

Also, with the correct conditions, the order of your predicates no longer matters. This is because your clauses properly then only operate under the conditions they are supposed to. Without it, your `pred(N, [N|T]) :- ...` clause, which is only intended to operate when `N > 1` will also attempt to run when `N =< 1`. Swapping the clause order only hides this issue and only somewhat. Order can, however, be important for efficiency.